# How can I check if react-router is in context?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm migrating an AngularJS app to React little by little, and I would like to have a custom `RouterLink` React component that checks if `react-router` is in context so it can use `history`, and if not, falls back to usage of good old `window.location`. But I don't see any way of checking that in `react-router`'s documentation.

I tried using `withRouter` but it throws when not in context and an `ErrorBoundary` doesn't seem to catch the error.

Does anyone know how I could go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is Router context exposed in `react-router` package, i.e. `__RouterContext`, by using that you can check if router is avaiable:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { __RouterContext } from 'react-router';

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const router = useContext(__RouterContext);

  if (router) {
    // Router context is avaible
  } else {
    // Use window.location as router context is not availble in this component
  }

  return <SomeOtherComponent />
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that export. Although it would've been better to have an official API that wouldn't unexpectedly break in a future update, I don't see any other option so I'm marking this as the correct answer. I guess I'll lock the version for now. Thank you!

Comment: You’re welcome, I digged around once and knew there was some context exported so came up with the solution 

Comment: @yadielar You probably didn't see it because it isn't part of the public API.  I really wouldn't rely on this.  It seems very hacky.  Libraries that expose variables with `__` prefixes are typically meant for internal use.

Comment: I think it’s there since v4, currently react-router is v5

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap the hook in a `try/catch`:

```js
const {useState, useEffect, Fragment} = React;
const {useLocation, MemoryRouter} = ReactRouter;

const Cmp = () => {
  let loc;
  try {
    loc = useLocation();
  } catch (err) {
    return (
      <div>No Router Available</div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>Hello I can see {loc.pathname}</div>
  );
};

const App1 = () => {
  return (
    <Cmp/>
  );
};

const App2 = () => {
  return (
    <MemoryRouter>
      <Cmp/>
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App1 />, document.getElementById("app1"));
ReactDOM.render(<App2 />, document.getElementById("app2"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router@5.1.2/umd/react-router.js"></script>

<div id="app1"></div>
<div id="app2"></div>
```

Comment: It’s not recommended to use hooks conditionally.

Comment: @MuhammadAli It's not running conditionally.  It always fires.  The value of the hook is conditionally used which is absolutely fine.

Comment: Yes but you’ve to disable eslint rule to use it without any warnings, so i think rules are there for a reason. I tried it as well but then due to that warning i had to move away from this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `useInRouterContext`:

```js
import {useInRouterContext} from 'react-router'

function MyComponent() {
  const isInRouterContext = useInRouterContext()
  console.log(isInRouterContext) // `true` or `false`
  // ...
}
```