# How to detect if react-router is set?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom hook useLocation() in third party component.

This component behavior depends on the current route by default but can be used also in app without react-router (user of the component shouldn't care about it)

The problem is that when the component is used outside of react-router scope it throws an error:

```
Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
```

My question is how to know if I can use useLocation() hook (how to know if a component is in react-router context)?

Comment: Probable duplicate for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59992359/how-can-i-check-if-react-router-is-in-context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution from a similar question suggested by @Krzysztof Cieslinski is wrapping `useLocation()` hook in try/catch block:

```js
let path = ''
try {
  path = useLocation().pathname
} catch (e) {}
```